# sending mail using pear php in xampp

Tags: php

```
Below is my php code to send email.
```

I have configured xampp for squirrel  mail and hmail server.
am able to send mails locally but my php progam is working but am unable to receive mails.
how can i configure my smtp,pop and imap in xampp/hmail server.

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php"; 
$to = 'admin@hatsoff.com';
$subject = 'Customer_Details Report';
$msg="php mail";
$headers = 'From: abd@abd.com' . "\r\n" ;  

$result=mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

if($result)
{
print 'mail sent';
}
else 
{
print 'mail not sent';
}
?>
```

Comment: There are quite a few problems with PHP's `mail()` function, it's difficult to use, and even more difficult to use correctly & securely. I would *highly* recommend you use [Swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHPMailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need live emails you could consider a local SMTP mail catching program such as :

http://download-codeplex.sec.s-msft.com/Download/Release?ProjectName=smtp4dev&DownloadId=269147

I ended up using it to test out my sent emails etc, much easier than configuring mail servers and the such, especially if you jump around on different computers.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the official documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

You will need to edit the php.ini file of your PHP runtime.

Also you should think about possible security issues, spam prevention like using captchas etc.

Comment: SMTP = localhost,sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost.is that it?

Comment: In case your system is a configured smtp server - usually yes. In case it isn't you should have a look at dovecot or similar.

Comment: I should also mention: after changing values in your php.ini you might need to restart your webserver.

Comment: my system is no configured smtp server and am using xampp and hmail server(mail server) to send and recieve emails.so how can i configure my php.ini,send mail.ini files in xampp.(to send emails using php programs.)

Answer (score 0):

go through this link :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

and also edit php.ini file.

i think this is work fine for you.